# How do I completely block port using firewalld?

Tags: centos, firewall, centos7, firewalld

<sup>Disclaimer: It's the first time I use firewalld, be gentle :) .</sup>

---

I have a CentOS machine and I want to implement the following requirements using firewalld:

- Allow connections from anywhere to ports 1, 2, 3, 4.
- Allow connections to port 5 only from IP addresses IP1, IP2 and IP3
- Completely block connections to port 6, from anywhere.

So I did this:

- added the ports 1, 2, 3 and 4 to the `public` zone
- added port 5 and IP addresses IP1, IP2 and IP3 to zone `trusted`

Now the zones look like this:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eno12345
  sources:
  services: ssh dhcpv6-client
  ports: 1/tcp 2/tcp 3/tcp 4/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: IP1 IP2 IP3
  services:
  ports: 5/tcp
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
```

Note: `public` is the default zone.

So the first 2 rules seem to be applied correctly.

However I got stuck with the final rule (completely block port 6). I tried multiple solutions and none seem to work.

1). What should I do to apply this?

2). How come I can connect through port 6 even though it's not explicitly listed as allowed in the firewalld configuration? No rule about it is added in `iptables` either.

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved it is I added a rich rule in the `trusted` zone:

```
rule family="ipv4" port port="6" protocol="tcp" drop
```

From what I know, rich rules are applied first. It seems to be working correctly in my case.

Answer (score 2):

Some generic command are below

```
firewall-cmd --list-ports
firewall-cmd --get-zones
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=5000/tcp
```

#Updated the url Aleksandar Pavić reported, Thanks Aleksandar Pavić

For some more docs and more details, please check it.
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/security_guide/sec-controlling_traffic#sec-Controlling_Ports_using_CLI

Comment: Link is dead 404...